# Minimize Waypoints Why Still Maintaining Distance From Objects for Motion Planning?

Tags: motion-planning, path-planning, occupancygrid

I'm working on a project where I want to give instruction to blindfolded participants on how to walk around an obstacle course. I'll map out my room and convert it to a grid map. However, given that I want to minimize the amount of instruction(turns) to give to each person, what algorithm can I use that minimize the amount of waypoints generated, as well as gives some room from obstacles, kind of like in in a potential field algorithm?

My biggest challenge right now is how to convert the path into a series of waypoints that are less granular than the original path. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to _Robotics_, itisyee. This is an interesting question, but it's probably not necessary to develop an entirely new approach. What has your web searching turned up? What have you tried? Please edit your question to include this. Also take a look at [How to Ask](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [_Robotics_ question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) for guidelines on how to write a good question.

Comment: @r-bryan Thank you for your commend. I looked up basic path finding methods like Dijkstra's, potential field methods, and RRT, and each have characteristics that I want, but I have not found a way to combine them all to do what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, the easiest way to remove waypoints is to simply skip every 1 or 2 or ## waypoints in your Dijkstra or A* (or similarly navigated) map. You do this by looking at the list of nodes to travel to and literally ignoring specifically chosen nodes. Not only do you have to create a path plan for your robot (or people), you need to create a separate algorithm on top of the navigation algorithm that takes care of removing waypoints.

This can be done in a smarter way by looking at the 2-D gradients. In other words, if the grid were an image, you would pass the image through an edge detector filter and try to place straight lines or curves over the edges with fitting algorithms (splines come to mind here).

The problem here is that you need to start from a high precision map, and then remove points to create a low precision map until you start to intersect obstacles or other experiment constraints. The parameters of precision aka. the resolution of the map (like an image) are experiment specific, and are therefore outside the scope of robotics stack exchange. In other words, the "simplification" of the map is an entirely separate problem to path planning.

Note: I am sure there are algorithms that do this automatically, I simply don't know them. Algos like RRT can take advantage of simplification, but those aren't grid based like the question suggests as a requirement, but I may be reading too far into the question.

Comment: The CS founder's name is spelled "Dijkstra" (couldn't edit it myself)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Dijkstra a really simple to understand and implement algorithm is APF, which stands for Artificial Potential Field. The main idea behind it is that you "build" a potential field in the space so that the robot/participant is attracted by the goal and repelled by the obstacles. The total potential field is the sum of attractive and repulsive potentials. Applying a gradient decent on top of that would find an optimal solution for your problem. The problems with this algo is that you might get stuck to local minimals, and it's performance is poor in dynamic environment.